# iOS 8 photoKit how to edit images using photoKit

Tags: photo, ios8

I am new to iOS 8, I want to edit an input image using photoKit such as blur, rotation, colour change, creating gradient etc. I've searched, there is no tutorials for it, so please share detailed ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through WWDC 2014 - 511 session which explains photos framework . You can also get the sample from [Using PhotoKit](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2014/wwdc_2014_sample_code/exampleappusingphotosframework.zip).

Comment: Thanks @Yatheesha, Any tutorials,,

Comment: @Rajapandian no, its shows error. plist file is missing. and then there are some objective c errors